# Show calendar on website

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm buildning a simple website with HTML and CSS and one feature will be a calendar that visitors will see. The only thing they can see is if a day is booked or available. Nothing more.

My problem is that I must sync this calendar from a real calender(Google Calendar for example). Caus I or someone else need to login to the calendar and change a date to booked/available.

What is my best approach for this? I have looked some at Google Calendar API but not sure if it's too much. And for Javascript it says I need Python which I never worked with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) There's nothing in Google Calendar API which requires Python, except to run their demo server. Think about it - in production for JS solution, you make an ajax call from your browser (JS) to their API (via HTTP). No Python anywhere. It's only needed to host the demo, and you can skip that entirely and just start building your site, either with their JS client library or write your own set of ajax calls.

Comment: 2) asking for recommendations is technically off-topic, but I will say that fullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io) can integrate directly with Google Calendar for a read-only view, with minimal coding on your part. just follow these instructions: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ . Other products may be available :-)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this more :) In my opinion the calendars you can embedd look a bit boring so I'm looking for something like this more: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/even-better-calendar and ofcourse style it a little more :)

Comment: as far as I can see that example is a datepicker, not a calendar that can display events. if you want to change fullCalendar's appearance though, you can make a theme (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/theme/) using jQueryUI, or you can write some entirely custom CSS to override the defaults.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I was more into the style of showing dates. My idea is to change color to green or red depending if there is a event on that day. So there can only be one event per day and if it exists, the "box" will turn red :)

Comment: no need to do that really - if there's an event that day, it will be obvious already because the event will be displayed in it. If there's no event, it will be blank.

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting fullCalendar. Exactly what I was looking for. Can style it pretty much how I want so just gonna hook it up with Google Calendar :) One question though, is it safe to have the API key in the javascript? Never worked with this kind of authorization before.

Comment: well since in order for it to work the calendar has to be public anyway, no-one can steal any more data than you've already publicised. That key only allows certain limited operations involving requests that don't require authorisation. You can't use it to insert data, for example. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication for a bit more detail

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing that out :)